# Does Paypal Permission Service support v.zero SDK?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I know Paypal Permission Service supports Express Checkout, that is, it allows one to charge on behalf of other users.

Does Permission Service also support Braintree's v.zero SDK? That is, can I use v.zero to charge on behalf of other users?